Mockito5 chained call inside MockedConstruction
I am new to Mockito 5 and trying to chain the call inside MockedConstruction block. I understand MockedConstruction.constructed() will return a new/different mock object for each instantiation. I am trying to find out if there is any workaround to chain the thenReturn()(or thenThrow()) in the MockedConstruction block other than write multiple test cases.
public class A {
    private final String test;

    public A(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String check() {
        return "checked " + this.test;
    }
}

public class TestService {
    public String purchaseProduct(String param) {
        A a = new A(param);
        return a.check();
    }
}

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedConstruction;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class ConstructorMockTest {
    private MockedConstruction<A> mockAController;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beginTest() {
        //create mock controller for all constructors of the given class
        mockAController = Mockito.mockConstruction(A.class,
                (mock, context) -> {
                    //implement initializer for mock. Set multiple return value for object A mock methods
                    when(mock.check()).thenReturn(" Constructor Mock A ").thenReturn(" Constructor Mock A again");
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        TestService service = new TestService();
        String serviceResult1 = service.purchaseProduct("test");
        //ensure that service returned value  from A mock
        Assertions.assertEquals(serviceResult1, " Constructor Mock A ");

        String serviceResult2 = service.purchaseProduct("test");
        //The test case fails at assertEquals() below 
        //because the newly instantiated
        // mock will always call the first thenReturn() and the remaining 
        // thenReturn() can never be reached
        Assertions.assertEquals(serviceResult2, " Constructor Mock A again");
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void endTest() {
        mockAController.close();
    }
}

